# Comparing vectors with numbers?

Tags: notation

My question pertains to the paper ["A Simplified Proof of the Divergence Theorem"](http://docdro.id/E0I6BtA) by Djairo Guedes de Figueiredo.

It's not a big question, actually, but it's confusing me a lot: In the statement of Lemma 2 in the paper, the author writes "$h(x') < x_1 < 1$ and $-1 < x' < 1$", where $x'=(x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$.

Why the statement $-1 < x' < 1$ makes sense? Because we can't compare vectors with numbers using inequalities: $-1$ and $1$ are numbers and $x'$ is a coordinate pair of the last $n-1$ coordinates of the vector $x=(x_1,x')=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $-1 < x' < 1$ means that every coordinate of $x'$ is between $-1$ and $1$. (The set of all such $x'$ is a cube.)

Comment: Am I at least correct in saying that is it still mathematically meaningless to write something like $(x,y) < 2$? But then again I'm guessing in research mathematics we abuse notation all the time, and that $(x,y) < 2$ is to be understood and interpreted as $\{(x,y) \mid x < 2, y < 2\}$.

Comment: I would say the expression is "ambiguous", rather than "meaningless", because it certainly can be given a well-defined meaning. I don't know whether I have ever seen $(x,y) < 2$, but it is quite common to write $x > 0$ to mean that every coordinate of $x$ is greater than 0.